# Error in calling a function from within another function in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to write a program where there will be two functions with large blocks of code. Each of the functions will be calling a few smaller functions. Now, in the main program body, I need to call the two larger functions. I am using arrays in the program.

I have done a sample but I am getting errors. Kindly please rectify my code. I am quite a newbie in this field. So please help.

```
# include <stdio.h>

unsigned char a[4] = {5, 3, 6, 2};
unsigned char b[4] = {3, 5, 2, 5};
unsigned char c[4] = {4, 2, 5, 7};
unsigned char x[4];
unsigned char y[4];

void add(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
  int k;
  for (k=0; k<3; k++)
  {
   num3[k] = num1[k] + num2[k]);
  }
}

void mul(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
  int k;
  for (k=0; k<3; k++)
  {
    num3[k] = num1[k] * num2[k]);
  }
}

void test1(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
  add(num1, num2, num3);
  mul(num1, num2, num3);
}

void test2(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2)
{
  add(num1, num2, num1);
}

void main() 
{
  int i,j ;

  test1(a,b,x);
  test2(c,y);

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",(x[i]);
  }
  printf(" ");

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", y[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please learn about creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Please post compiling code: in function `add()`, you have `num3[k] = num1[k] + num2[k]);` and don't need the close parenthesis.  This occurs several times — you should be able to fix that without needing to ask on SO.  You have a stray open parenthesis at `printf("%d ",(x[i]);` before the `x`.

Comment: There are extra `)`s on lines 14, 23, and 49. And don't use `void main()`, always use `int main()`

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your add and mul functions. In both cases, the loop should go until k < 4.

Comment: All comments and fixes consolidated under one [**community-wiki answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18030123/319204)

Answer (score 1):

There were several compilation and logical errors :

- **Compilation errors** :

  - Missing closing brace **`}`**
  - Missing closing bracket **`)`**
  - Extra closing bracket **`)`**
- **Logical errors** :

  - Invalid array bounds check

> **Proper indentation** goes a long way in easily identifying such issues with mis-matched brackets and braces to fix otherwise seemingly cryptic errors like **"expected ; before ..."**.

Here is your corrected code with inline comments describing the errors and fix.

```
# include <stdio.h>

unsigned char a[4] = {5, 3, 6, 2}; 
unsigned char b[4] = {3, 5, 2, 5}; 
unsigned char c[4] = {4, 2, 5, 7}; 
unsigned char x[4];
unsigned char y[4];

void add(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
        int k;
        for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                /* removed extra closing bracket */
                num3[k] = num1[k] + num2[k];
        }   
}

void mul(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
        int k;
        /* fixed value of array bounds check */
        for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                num3[k] = num1[k] * num2[k];
        }   
}

void test1(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2, unsigned char* num3)
{
        add(num1, num2, num3);
        mul(num1, num2, num3);
}

void test2(unsigned char* num1, unsigned char* num2)
{
        add(num1, num2, num1);
}

int main() 
{
        int i,j ;

        test1(a,b,x);
        test2(c,y);

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
                /* added missing closing bracket */
                printf("%d ",(x[i]));
        /* added missing closing brace */
        }   

        printf(" ");

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
                printf("%d ", y[i]);
        }   
}
```

Comment: The return type of `main()` should be `int`, even on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler done. Feel free to make additional changes as deemed fit.

Comment: @SohiniBasu Because it's against the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is 4 items, but you are using index <3

```
for (k=0; k<3; k++)
```

should be

```
for (k=0; k<4; k++)
```

And here you have an extra `)`

```
num3[k] = num1[k] + num2[k]);
num3[k] = num1[k] * num2[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parenthesis where there shouldn't be after num2[k], and change the loop they are in from < 3 to <=3. You missed a ( in  printf( "%d ", (x[i]) )

Answer (score 0):

It appears that x and y are uninitialized so passing y into test2 results in garbage values being passed into the second parameter of add.

Answer (score 0):

`num3[k] = (num1[k] + num2[k]); //fix bracket`

`printf("%d ",x[i]); //fix bracket`

Comment: **`}`** is a closing brace. **`)`** is simply a closing bracket